# Passing Parsed Data from the Parent view to Child view using segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

i been wanting to pass a data in the textfield of my selected cell, but im getting a full array of that parsed data where i NSLog the data it let me sees what data im passing and also the thing is when i click on any cell it gives me an exception, which is below

```
[UITableViewController setParentKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7169670
2013-08-29 17:37:58.937 [8322:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setParentKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7169670'
```

As im getting an Array of data from the indexPathForSelectedRow.row i have a MutableArray initialized to catch the passed data in my destination view, my segue code goes like that too, what am i doing wrong here?

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        ChildTableViewController *myNextPage = [segue destinationViewController];
        myNextPage.parentKey = [[parsedData listPopulated]objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        NSLog(@"segue value = %@", [[parsedData listPopulated]objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does `ChildTableViewController` has `parentKey` property?

Comment: Are you calling prepareForSegue: in init method? Try to call it in viewDidLoad or some other place

Comment: yes, its an NSMutableArray, coz im passing a kind of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting a `ChildTableViewController` but receiving a `UITableViewController`.  Make sure your segue is navigating to what you think.  You can also add this:

```
if ([myNextPage isKindOfClass:[ChildTableViewController class]])
```

That will likely prevent the crash, but if the segue is misconfiguration to go to the wrong view controller, you will need to fix that as well for the segue to do anything.

[image]

Comment: yup this did the trick, but when I try to check the received data, there is non, i've tried NSLog in viewDidLoad for the parentKey nothing prints out in my console. Its like viewDidLoad is non even being called.

Comment: @AceMunim Assuming you are using storyboards, check and make sure the controller you are segueing too is set to `ChildTableViewController`.  (Click on the view controller in the story board and define `Custom Class`)

Answer (score 0):

Error showing that you are trying to set the `parentKey` property of `UITableViewController` in fact `UITableViewController` doesn't have a property called `parentKey`. So make sure that you properly set the class of your  view controller in storyboard to `ChildTableViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`